# Spotify Integration failing with openURL Swift

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I am integrating Spotify in one of my application. I am getting the following error inspite of adding required URL schemes in info.plist:

**-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify:" - error: "(null)"**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the direct translation I just made. It should have all the answers you need on what to do. https://github.com/Sethmr/SpotifyInSwift

Answer (score 0):

- From what I have read in other discussion forums make sure that after you have added the **redirect_uri** in the developer portal from Spotify, also save your changes its all the way at bottom up.

I'm also having issues with this an using swift I get a 200 code and a web page printed in my console as plain html, when I put it in chrome is a 404 page.

Also another tip:

Im using `http://localhost:8888/callback` as my redirect uri after running a simple nodejs server.

I'm having a doubt about this url encoding inside query string as the examples show %3A%2A%2A for `://` and when I print the entire URL it doesn't show them like that